# can't store objects x and y coordinate in flash actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

can't seem to store coordinate using this codes

```
    var collisions:Array = _collisionList.checkCollisions();
    if(collisions.length)
    {
        var tempX:Number = 0;
        var tempY:Number = 0;

        _speedX = 0;
        _speedY = 0;
        _wheel.vx = 0;
        _wheel.vy = 0;

        if(tempX==0 || tempY== 0){
            trace(_wheel.x+" "+_wheel.y);
            if(_speedX>0) tempX = _wheel.x - .5;//GOING RIGHT
            if(_speedX<0) tempX = _wheel.x + .5;

            if(_speedY>0) tempY = _wheel.y - .5;//GOING DOWN
            if(_speedY<0) tempY = _wheel.y + .5;

            trace(tempX+" "+tempY);
        }

        //_wheel.x = tempX;
        //_wheel.y = tempY;
    }
    else{

        //_wheel.vy += GRAVITY;

        //Moves Hero
        _wheel.vx += _speedX;
        _wheel.vy += _speedY;

        //Slows down hero's motion.
        _wheel.vy *= FRICTION;
        _wheel.vx *= FRICTION;

        //Updates hero's position.
        _wheel.x += _wheel.vx;
        _wheel.y += _wheel.vy;

        if(_wheel.x > stage.stageWidth) _wheel.x = stage.stageWidth;
        if(_wheel.x < /*0*/stage.stageWidth*-1) _wheel.x = stage.stageWidth*-1
        if(_wheel.y > stage.stageHeight - (_wheel.height >> 1) )//reset ball.
        {
            //_wheel.y = 10;
            //_wheel.x = 30;
            //_wheel.vx = _wheel.vy = 0;
        }

    }
```

tried changing tempX, tempY to float or decimal or double but AS3 doesn't read it as a valid variable type. i'm coding this inside a class btw any solution to this prob?

updated 2: for reference.

```
private function keyPressed(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        var collisions:Array = _collisionList.checkCollisions();
        if(collisions.length)
        {
            _speedX = 0;
            _speedY = 0;
            _wheel.vx = 0;
            _wheel.vy = 0;
        }

        // _speed* increments the longer the key is pressed.            
        else
        {
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) _speedX = -.5;// -.5 axisX/sec
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) _speedX = .5;
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) _speedY = -.5;
            if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) _speedY = .5;
        }
    }


    private function keyReleased(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        _speedX = 0;
        _speedY = 0;
    }
```

this is how speedX and speedY's value changes.

Comment: Can't do a boolean or like that, if I'm reading your code correctly - have to do `tempX==0 || tempY==0`

Comment: changed it from if((tempX || tempY) == 0) to if(tempX==0 || tempY== 0) still can't store coordinates.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or just unexpected behavior? What is the error/behavior? Also, out of curiousity, why do that `if`? You just set them to 0 - it will always be true.

Comment: Should `_wheel.x`, `_wheel.vx` and `_wheel.y`, `_wheel.vy` be different, or is that a typo?

Comment: i only found that code and i'm rewriting it for personal use. before i store the wheel coords to temp x & y i check it out first just to be sure. then when the conditions are satisfied i put the wheel coords in the temps but ever time i run it temp x & y always return a value of 0.

Comment: `_wheel.vx` and `_wheel.vy` are diff from `_wheel.x` and `_wheel.y`

Comment: how does `_speedX` & `_speedY` get changed?  You don't show them ever able to be anything but 0 in your code, so none of your tempX assignments will ever happen (except the declarations at the top)

Comment: `_speed x and y` changes when i press on a key and\or when i release a key.

Comment: You're setting `_speedX` and y to 0 right before your if statement, so the values will always be 0 when you check them by doing `if(_speedX > 0)`

Comment: @LDMS aw fudge... no wonder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your values aren't being stored, is because the `if` condition is never being met:  (See my code comments)

```
    _speedX = 0; //you don't want to set this here
    _speedY = 0;  //or this
    _wheel.vx = 0; //and probably not this either
    _wheel.vy = 0;  // or this

    if(tempX==0 || tempY== 0){
        trace(_wheel.x+" "+_wheel.y);

        //Since above you just set _speedX to 0, this condition will not be met.
        if(_speedX>0) tempX = _wheel.x - .5;

        //Since above you just set _speedX to 0, this condition will not be met.
        if(_speedX<0) tempX = _wheel.x + .5;

        //Since above you just set _speedY to 0, this condition will not be met.
        if(_speedY>0) tempY = _wheel.y - .5;

        //Since above you just set _speedY to 0, this condition will not be met.
        if(_speedY<0) tempY = _wheel.y + .5;

        trace(tempX+" "+tempY);
    }
```

Take out all four assignments (`_speedX`, `_speedY`, `_wheel.x`, `_wheel.y`) at the top, and it should work the way you want.